# newlfm - addrfrom and addrto on the same vertical height

Tags: floats, vertical-alignment, newlfm

Is there a way to put addrfrom and addrto on the same vertical height when one of them is left-justified and another is aligned to the right? This is basically the layout I'm trying to achieve:

```
--------------------------
[\addrto]      [\addrfrom]

...

[\greetto]
[...msg...]
--------------------------
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `\addrto` macro to manually place both addresses using `\parbox`es:

```
\documentclass[stdletter,addrtoleft]{newlfm}

\nameto{George Bush} 
\namefrom{Paul Thompson} 

\newlength\lento
\newlength\lenfrom
\setlength\lento{2in}% width of the box for \addrto
\setlength\lenfrom{2in}% width of the box for \addrfrom

\addrto{\parbox[t]{\lento}{The White House \\ Washington, DC}%
  \hspace{\dimexpr\textwidth-\lento-\lenfrom}%
  \parbox[t]{\lenfrom}{\raggedleft The Pink House in Avon \\ Belleville, IL}}

\greetto{Dear Mr. Bush,}

\begin{document}

\closeline{Sincerely yours,} 

\begin{newlfm}
How are the azaleas?
\end{newlfm}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! And pardon me for the huge delay. I couldn't figure out the letrinfo.tex error and thought that my texlive installation was broken. \o/

Comment: In order to suppress some of the whitespace it is possible to add \vspace{-1cm} inside the \addrto.